# Can I update a remote javascript file of an android app with chrome developers tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Using ctrl+s it says "Changes to this file were not saved to the file system"

Answer (score 0):

The changes you made will stay until you don't reload the page. Please read [change to this file were not saved to file system error in google chrome version 30.0.1599.101 m](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654081/change-to-this-file-were-not-saved-to-file-system-error-in-google-chrome-version) for more info.

Comment: So there is no chance of doing it @BHAWANI?

Comment: if you have the source you may add the directory, please check the link in the answer for that.